# Alias ​​for class with many typeparams in other class body (C#)

Tags: c#, alias, using, genetic

I declare a class with many typeparams:

```
public class A<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5> {}
```

How can I use alias like this:

```
public class B<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>
{
    using T = A<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>

    public void Method()
    {
        T.StaticMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont understand your question.  It looks like you simply want class `B` to have an instance of class `A` so you can call it's members.  Is that true?

Comment: C # allows to declare alias only in the namespace, not in class. But I don't want using long declaration of class, I want using alias.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the rest of your using statements:

```
using MyList = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, string>;
```

Then you can use the class like so:

```
MyList x = new MyList();
x.Add(0, "Hello World");
```

However, this is kinda bad design. In the example you posted, B still had 5 generic type arguments, so nothing much is gained.

Comment: In my class I need to use 5 generic type arguments. The problem is that I need to use generic type arguments in class A from class B.

Comment: You're not gaining anything by the obscurity then. Simply invoke `A<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>.StaticMethod()` then

Comment: I use it now. I found article in blog on MSDN Blogs: [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2009/10/23/using-c-dynamic-to-call-static-members.aspx). But perhaps there is a simple solution?